# How To Finish Completion Block - Swift / Stripe Payments

Tags: swift, stripe-payments, completionhandler

This is the block I have:

```
func createBackendChargeWithToken(_ token: STPToken, completion: @escaping STPTokenSubmissionHandler) {
    if backendChargeURLString != "" {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://wt-lightfalldev-gmail-com-0.run.webtask.io/stripe-payment/payment") {
           let chargeParams : [String: AnyObject] = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId as AnyObject, "amount": shirtPrice as AnyObject]

           Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: chargeParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: heads).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

               switch(response.result) {
               case .success(_):
                  if response.result.value != nil{
                      print(response.result.value!)
                  }
                  break

               case .failure(_):
                  print(response.result.error!)
                  break                        
               }
           }
       }
   }
   completion(STPBackendChargeResult.failure, NSError(domain: StripeDomain, code: 50, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "You created a token! Its value is \(token.tokenId!). Now configure your backend to accept this token and complete a charge."]))
}
```

but this needs to be in it but I don't know how to write it correctly:

```
if (error) {  
    completion(STPBackendChargeResultFailure, error);
} else {
    completion(STPBackendChargeResultSuccess, nil);
}
```

The code is always calling the completion callback with `STPBackendChargeResult.failure`. So it needs to be an if statement and I need to call the completion callback with either `failure` or `success` depending on the result of the Alamofire request to send the token to the backend server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just put it in the switch?

```
switch(response.result) {
case .success(_):
    if response.result.value != nil{
        print(response.result.value!)            
    }
    completion(STPBackendChargeResultSuccess, nil)
case .failure(_):
    print(response.result.error!)
    completion(STPBackendChargeResultFailure, error)
}
```

Comment: If I put it in the switch I get a never ending loading sign on the "pay" button. So no that doesn't work.

Comment: In any case, completion callback should be inside the response block of the alamofire's method, you only know if there is an error or not there. You can try putting second part of your code (the if statement) just over the switch. Something can also be wrong with the code inside the completion handler.

Comment: Also, as an idea, if you have some UI updating code inside the completion block, you need to dispatch it into the main thread (may be this + my answer will work together).

Comment: Hmm, no I have tried both your answers but still nothing. The thing is that there are two errors or two success messages. Which is why it has to be outside, 1. from the app, creating the token, and sending that to the back end and to stripe. And then 2. Stripe verifying the token and charging the card, causing a success and error there. I've been searching, but I can't find any solution in case my Alamofire request is wrong but I don't think so because when I do it in command line and send a curl through there, I get a success message.

Comment: This is what Stripe says to do:  "In your case, you'd simply need to call `completion` in each of your existing `case` blocks, with the correct status (success or failure) and an error message in case of failure." So maybe you are right?

Comment: You were right, it was a backend issue! One more question, How could I make this only pass completion if it matches this message: {
    message = "Payment done!";
}

if response.result.value != nil {
    print(response.result.value!) 
}

The point is because thats the message Stripe returns after a succesful charge, but calling a completion when message is != nil doesn't make sense because it can be not be nil but return an error from Stripe

Comment: So in the alamofire's `.success` case you can have stripe's `.success` and`.failure` cases, did I get it correct? Then inside the `.success` case in the switch you already have, you need to get real stipe's response (is it in the `value`? I don't know, haven't use alamofire yet) and `switch {}` on the status of this response. Don't rely on the message (I don't even know, whose property is this, but checking exact content of a string is never good idea).